# How to trigger a DevOps release pipeline based on a build pipeline's path filter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Function App that includes 3 functions:

- FunctionApp

  - FunctionA
  - FunctionB
  - FunctionC

I have a DevOps pipeline configured to build the function app whenever any of the contents of the FunctionApp change.

I'd like now to set up a release pipeline that invokes whichever functions were updated. For example, if, in my pull request, only FunctionA was modified, I'd like to invoke only FunctionA.

How can I do this with DevOps pipelines?

Comment: Devops pipeline triggers build with changes in repos, it knows when one git branch has changes, but it won't know when specific(functionA, B or C) files change. So it seems not to be possible.

Comment: Triggers can also be filtered by path.

Answer (score -1):

I don't want to say "impossible", but what you're asking for is difficult-verging-on-impossible.

Without building a full dependency graph of the application code and tying it back to changed source files, you can't tell which function changed. Here's an example:

Let's say Function A and Function B depend on Library C. You update code in Library C. This means that from a functional perspective, both Function A and Function B have changed. How you determine this at build time?

It starts to get even trickier when you start to consider not only build, but deployment -- because you'd really be invoking the function after *deployment*, not build. Here's a scenario: Function A and Function B both change, but something goes wrong and the deployment is only partially successful and only Function A has been invoked. Now you run the deployment again. How does it know to invoke only Function B, since A has already been run?

You haven't said anything about what the actual purpose of the functions are, but I suspect that a better solution to this problem is to ensure that your functions are idempotent and can safely be run multiple times. If you do that, the entire premise of the question is moot, you can just deploy and invoke all of the functions every time.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think you may have overthought this by an order of magnitude.

First, assume that the functions are independent; a change in Function A only affects function A. Code updates in shared libraries are an edge case that I'll handle manually.

Second, the functions are idempotent. However, these are long-running functions and I'd rather not run them unneccessarily. If I change Function A, I want to trigger only Function A, and not consume the resources to also run Functions B and C.